# How to install large dependencies on AWS EFS via serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, tensorflow2.0, serverless-framework, amazon-efs

I understand that we can install dependencies in **EFS** from an **EC2 instance** and then set the mount path and PythonPath in AWS lambda so that the lambda has now the path of the dependencies folder.

But is there a way to eliminate the EC2 from this approach and rather install those dependencies from **[serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/getting-started/)**?

My scenario is to upload a tensorflow2 dependency(which is >500 MB) to an AWS lambda.

Any leads would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I am not sure if you have already setup EFS on serverless.
But assuming that this have been done, you can then explicitly tell your serverless lambda project what vpc's to connect to and what EFS IAM roles to use.

I do not have the details of the EFS setup but on my project this would look something like this:

```
  name: aws
  profile: abcd
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-west-1
  
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-065647b2292ad63a2
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-02ad3xxxxxxxxxxxx
      - subnet-02ca2xxxxxxxxxxxx
      - subnet-01a14xxxxxxxxxxxx
  # Allow RW access to EFS services
  iamManagedPolicies:
    - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemClientReadWriteAccess"
```

under the functions section just make sure that you define your env vars to point to your libs/code:

```
functions:
  myfunc:
    runtime: python3.8
    handler: myhandler
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: /mnt/efs/lib/python3.8/site-packages
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /mnt/efs/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Finally in resources:

```
resources:
  extensions:
    MyfuncLambdaFunction:
      Properties:
        FileSystemConfigs:
          - Arn: arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-1:123456789012:access-point/fsap-0012abcde1234ab12
            LocalMountPath: /mnt/efs
```

FYI for tensorflow, you can bring it down to around 60MB using a combination of
lambc/docker-lambda and

[tensorflow packaging](https://github.com/Beomi/aws-lambda-py3/blob/master/tensorflow/v2.0.0-alpha/Dockerfile)

but in the long run you will be better off with EFS anyway, just was worth mentioning.

Comment: so this can create EFS and as well install dependencies in the EFS at the required path?

Comment: No. What I have described will allow your serverlass stack to communicate with an EFS setup through a VPN that you or your DevOps person will need to setup separately. For exanple, we have another separate EFS cloudformation stack that has been deployed using a EC2 instance. This is for say a Dev environment. Then, whenever a developer creates a development env serverless project, he needs to add to his serverless script the params and properties that I have described previously. The required path is set by your DevOps, possibly via a venv setup.

Comment: we got chance to deploy this today, but was failing because the serverless tries to deploy the resources section prior to the lambda functions, but here these extensions are waiting to connect to lambda function, right?

Comment: Can I see the error log? Have you already set an independent EFS environment in AWS?

Comment: does the extension require any serverless plugins ? It gives me this error : 
```  Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Invalid template property or properties [extensions]```

Comment: we also get the same error as @SagarJani when we try adding "`resources:  extensions:`"